# Windows Store App Customized Background Color

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to have a customized background color for the windows store app splash screen ?
I tried using color codes but it throws an error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The splash screen colour is set in your app manifest, in the "Background Color" option under the "Splash Screen" heading. It is likely the last thing in the "Application UI" tab in the manifest editor. You need to use a six digit hexidecimal colour code preceded by a pount sign, like `#rrggbb`.

Comment: I tried the method you told earlier but I used a 8 digit hexadecimal color code, eg.#FF4962D1. It worked after I removed the 'FF'. Any logic behind it ?

Comment: @ranjith FF4962D1 is ARGB format and I don't think that your background theme supports semi transparent theme thus only RGB are allowed